# php variable in mysql using get method

Tags: php, mysql

in mysql table has 3 column id,name,addr
id is auto increment & name and addr has values and I want to get result using get method but it is just showing parse error.
.
.
.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (empty($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    echo 'A valid image file id (numeric) is required to display the image file.';
    exit;
} else {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imgtable where id={$id}");
    while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
?>
<tr><td> <?php echo $res['name']; ?></td><td><img src="<?php echo $res['addr']; ?>" width='200px' height='200px'/></td></tr>
<?php}} ?>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: mysql_* functions have been removed in PHP7 and deprecated after PHP5.3. I'd recommend switching to [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). It will also fix your SQL injection vulnerability here.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM imgtable where id='$id'");
```

Instead of

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imgtable where id={$id}");
```

Obviously, if you switch to `mysqli`, also use `mysqli_fetch_array` in the followng.

Comment: Although `mysqli` is is a better idea, and PDO even better still, this "fix" is unlikely to change anything meaningful.

Comment: `mysqli_query` also requires a connection.